# How do I undo a git reset --hard origin/bejing

Tags: git, github

I was working on a project. I accidentally added some file I shouldn't have to my local git repo (very large copy of a db). Github rejected the pushes to github because the file size was to large.

So I needed to remove all the commits and go back to where I was. I did the following, which was a huge mistake.

```
git reset --hard origin/bejing
```

I shouldn't have reset to origin/bejing, but rather reset to just bejing. Or revert to a the last good commit of bejing.

Now when I try to commit I get this error.

```
    To https://github.com/blah/myapi.git
       40eeeb5..418805e  bejing -> bejing
    To git@heroku.com:blah-staging.git
     ! [rejected]        bejing -> master (non-fast-forward)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:blah-staging.git'
    To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
    Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  See the 'Note about
    fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

How do I fix this? I mean I want to go back to what I had yesterday where everything was working. I am not quite sure what `git reset --hard origin/bejing` did.

I am not sure why error is trying to push anything to the master branch? Master has not received any updates in 2 years? Why is it all of a sudden trying to push bejing to master (bejing -> master)?

Comment: You are getting the error (I believe) because your _local_ `origin/beijing` branch is behind the remote `beijing` branch.  You don't want to push this anyway, because it doesn't have the commits which you accidentally reset.  You need to use `git reflog`, and search for the commits which got nuked during the `git reset --hard origin/beijing`.  Then add these commits back to your branch, except for the bad commit with the monster file.

Comment: How do I add these commits back?

Comment: This is a tough question because much information is missing.  You can use `git reflog` and search for the commits.  Do this sooner rather than later.

Comment: I did a git reflog and it listed about 30 items. Now what?

Comment: Find your deleted commits,then cherry-pick them back into your local branch (except for the commit with the really large file -- leave that one out).